# passing POST request body through Amazon API Gateway to Lambda

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a AWS Lambda function written in Java, that gets triggered by an AWS API Gateway call.

I am trying to make a `POST` request to one of the endpoints with a JSON as payload.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"firstName":"Mr", "lastName":"Awesome"}' https://someexample.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/beta/MethodHandlerLambda
```

The gateway will then *detect* the `Content-Type` and pass all request parameters (including the body) through a default [template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html). The interesting part is this one

```
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
"body-json" : $input.json('$'),
 ....
```

It is supposed to present me with a `Map<String, Object>` that is passed to my Java method:

```
public void myHandler(Map<String, Object> input, Context context){
    input.keySet().forEach((key) -> {
        System.out.println(key + " : " + input.get(key));
    });
}
```

And the result *should* be something like this:

```
body-json : {"firstName":"Mr", "lastName":"Awesome"}
...
```

But what I am getting is this:

```
body-json : {firstName=Mr, lastName=Awesome}
```

Another possibility would be to pass the whole body as string:

```
"body" : $input.body
```

but that again just "converts" to `key=value` instead of `key:value`

**How do I have to configure the template to simply pass me the body so I can use it in a JSON parser?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And again - just posting a question here on SO helps to find the answer on your own :)

In the AWS Api Gateway template I set the body to

```
"body-json" : $input.body
```

which *should* return the complete payload as a String.

But more importantly I read [Greggs answer to his own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36654934/896249) and changed my *method* to

```
public void myHandler(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException{
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode json = objectMapper.readTree(inputStream);
    System.out.println(json.toString());        
}
```

So, it is sufficient to have a simple `InputStream` and read it as a `JsonNode` with whatever JSON library one prefers (I am using Jackson FasterXML). And voila, it packs all possible parameters in a single JSON (as specified by the template)

```
{
    "body-json": {
        "firstName": "Mr",
        "lastName": "Awesome"
    },
    "params": {
       ...
    },
    "stage-variables": {
       ...
    },
    "context": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to create a post request using $input.body.. But what is the use of $input.json('$').. if I have payload as Json .. how I can interpret it .. while going thru the below documentation at AWS site 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference
 
and also 

https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

I tried to retrieve the Json from the lambda .. but it gave me a blank curly brackets.